# Where did my color go on Vim

Tags: vim

So Vim was auto indenting with the hard tab and I wanted to do away with that. I created a new .vimrc on my Linux machine with the single line:

```
filetype indent off
```

Now whenever I go into vim it shows absolute no color except the default text color. What did this single line do to my poor vim? Did I do something wrong and how could this single line affect color on vim?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have a `.vimrc` file, Vim will load a `defaults.vim` file from the Vim runtime directory. The `defaults.vim` file shipped with Vim will enable options to make it more useful by default. Among the settings in `defaults.vim`, syntax highlighting and filetype indent plug-ins are enabled.

That's why you see such a big change when you create a very minimal `.vimrc`, as Vim will stop setting all the other settings from `defaults.vim`.

In order to preserve the options from `defaults.vim`, but revert its setting enabling filetype indent plug-ins, you might want to update your `.vimrc` to:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
filetype indent off
```

By explicitly sourcing the `defaults.vim` file, you'll keep all other settings from it as you introduce your own in your `.vimrc`.

See also:

- [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim)
- Contents of [`defaults.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.1.0948/runtime/defaults.vim) shipped with Vim.

Answer (score 0):

You might have removed (by not adding it to your new configuration document) the `syntax on` command, which activates syntax highlighting.